# How do I build opencv.js with seamlessClone?

Tags: javascript, opencv

Since the seamlessClone method is not available in the officially distributed opencv.js builds, I attempted to build my own opencv.js module by following the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html).

I added `'seamlessClone'` to the `photo` section in the opencv_js.config.py file and was able to build it successfully. The seamlessClone method is available in the browser but if I try to use it, I get an error "6607080" without any other information. I'm not sure I've added everything right to get seamlessClone working.

**Edit (19 November 2021)**:

Alright so I tweaked the coordinates of the center point a bit, from (50, 50) to (215, 63), the final command being:

`cv.seamlessClone(source, target, mask, new cv.Point(215, 63), dest, cv.NORMAL_CLONE)`

This is at least not throwing any errors, but the output is still not as expected. I've added the images in detail in a comment on this [github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17240#issuecomment-973865778).

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-build-opencv-js-with-seamlessclone/6272

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try MONOCHROME_TRANSFER instead of NORMAL_CLONE.

The command would look like

```
cv.seamlessClone(source, target, mask, new cv.Point(215, 63), dest, cv.MONOCHROME_TRANSFER)
```